# How to test checkboxes in custom listViews using Robotium in android

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I'm testing my android app using **robotium**, I have used fragments in my activity, can anyone tell me how to test `Checkboxes` present inside the custom `ListView`, I'm not able to get the indexes of the `CheckBox` to check or uncheck them..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use:

```
solo.clickOnCheckBox(set_here_cb_index);
```

So use:

```
solo.clickOnCheckBox(0); //to check or uncheck the first checkbox
solo.clickOnCheckBox(1); //for the second
```

Answer (score 2):

Something on the similarity of this:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) activity.findViewById (R.id.checkboxid);
cb.getVisibility () == View.VISIBLE; //example
```

Natali, and if the application is multilanguage? And if the time will change the value of the text? If pressed, then the ID is better. For example:

```
CheckBox all = (CheckBox) solo.GetView(R.id.checkboxid);
solo.clickOnView(all);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

```
solo.clickOnText("your CheckBox name");
```